# Babel how to add new line or line break to code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, babeljs, generator

I haven't found a way to add an empty line to my code with Babel. I have javascript code that is parsed with the Babel library. I have for example the following code:

```
var e = t && t.__esModule ? function () {
  return t.default;
} : function () {
  return t;
};
```

and I need to convert this into:

```
var e = t && t.__esModule ? function () {
  return t.default;
} : 
function () {
  return t;
};
```

I have tried to insert code before the function with

```
path.insertAfter(t.expressionStatement(t.stringLiteral('\n')))
```

but the Babel generator turns the code into:

```
var e = t && t.__esModule ? function () {
  return t.default;
} : ("\n", function () {
  return t;
});
```

I need to add line breaks at multiple places in the code for example also after a function opens with '{' or after '},'. How can I do this with Babel? Is there a different approach possible? Is there a Babel alternative?

Comment: Since Babel's transformations are aimed at transforming the semantic behavior of code, it has no APIs targeted at formatting, so this isn't really doable. What makes the specific formatting important here?

Comment: Instead of adding an edit to your question, [you might want to post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something which is impossible with an AST as @loganfsmyth pointed out. An AST removes intentionally information such as line breaks and whitespaces. What I was looking for was a Concrete Syntax Tree (CST) or a Linter. ESLint allowed me to add line breaks where required.